# jQuery, prevent form from submitting, then continue

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a simple form with 2 radio buttons and a checkbox. The checkbox is dependent on the radio button. Meaning, if the radio button with id="rd1" is checked, the checkbox should also be selected, otherwise the form should not be submitted.
If the radio button with id="rd0" is checked, the form can be submitted.

Here's how it's written:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="rd" value="0" id="rd0" required="required" />
<input type="radio" name="rd" value="1" id="rd1" required="required" />

<input type="checkbox" name="ckbx" value="sample_value" id="ck" />

<button type="submit" name="send" id="sbmt" >Submit Me!</button>
</form>
```

So, now I've written and tested 2 pieces of code using jQuery, but each are functioning differently.

First:

```
$('#sbmt').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#rd1').is(':checked') && $('#ck:checked').length == 0){
            alert('You didn't select the checkbox! /facepalm ');
        }else{
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

This piece of code, submits the form anyway! If I don't select any of the radio buttons, it wouldn't even trigger the browser alarm for the `required` attribute.

Now, the second piece of code:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#rd1').is(':checked') && $('#ck:checked').length == 0){
            alert('You didn't select the checkbox! /facepalm ');
        }else{
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

This, on the other hand, shows that alarm perfectly when `if` condition is true. But it won't submit the form when it's not. Needless to say that the `required` attribute of the radio buttons work flawless here.

Your help is 100% appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: $('form').submit() triggers the submit event like the browser does. So everytime you call $('form').submit() it will get event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a mistake with event.preventDefault().

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
        if($('#rd1').is(':checked') && $('#ck:checked').length == 0){
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent only when condition is true, otherwise submit
            alert('You didn't select the checkbox! /facepalm ');
        }
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for that. But I wonder, shouldn't that ```else``` condition work flawlessly since it's after the ```preventDefault```? Or does it go into a loop? Form submits, default is prevented, conditions happen, ```else``` part is true, form gets submitted again, default is again prevented, same story... Is it like that?